# How can I check if array contains value in Javascript for JSON data?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Pardon as I am new in the community and currently learning on applying Javascript and JSON for the below:

I am trying to match "id": 7,"name": "UPS", "parent_id": [3, 4] when user select either "id": 3 or "id": 4

May I know how should I implement .indexOf or .includes in my code below

index.html

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

 load_json_data('service');

 function load_json_data(id, parent_id)
 {
  var html_code = '';
  $.getJSON('data.json', function(data)
  {
   html_code += '<option value="">Select '+id+'</option>';
   $.each(data, function(key, value)
   {
    if(id == 'service')
    {
     if(value.parent_id == '0')
     {
      html_code += '<option value="'+value.id+'">'+value.name+'</option>';
     }
    }
    else
    {
     if(value.parent_id == parent_id)
     {
      html_code += '<option value="'+value.id+'">'+value.name+'</option>';
     }
    }
   });
   $('#'+id).html(html_code);
  });

 }

 $(document).on('change', '#service', function(){
  var service_id = $(this).val();
  if(service_id != '')
  {
   load_json_data('item', service_id);
   $('#contact').html('<option value="">Select contact</option>');
  }
  else
  {
   $('#item').html('<option value="">Select item</option>');
   $('#contact').html('<option value="">Select contact</option>');
  }
 });
 $(document).on('change', '#item', function(){
  var item_id = $(this).val();
  if(item_id != '')
  {
   load_json_data('contact', item_id);
  }
  else
  {
   $('#contact').html('<option value="">Select contact</option>');
  }
 });
});
</script>
```

data.json

```
[
 {
  "id": 1,
  "name": "Delivery",
  "parent_id": 0
 }, 
 {
  "id": 2,
  "name": "Repair",
  "parent_id": 0
 }, 
 {
  "id": 3,
  "name": "Quick Deliver",
  "parent_id": 1
 }, 
  {
  "id": 4,
  "name": "Slow Deliver",
  "parent_id": 1
 }, 
 {
  "id": 5,
  "name": "Aircon",
  "parent_id": 2
 }, 
 {
  "id": 6,
  "name": "Television",
  "parent_id": 2
 }, 
 {
  "id": 7,
  "name": "UPS",
  "parent_id": [3, 4]
 }, 
 {
  "id": 8,
  "name": "LG support",
  "parent_id": 5
 },
 {
  "id": 9,
  "name": "Toshiba support",
  "parent_id": 6
 }
]
```

Comment: is it an Array or JSON data? an Array, you can use `.find` method ... if it's JSON, you'd parse it to an object first, then use Array `.find` method

Comment: Just a quick way to show you one possible way.   `json.forEach( d => { if (d.arrayField.length > 1 ? d.arrayField.indexOf(3) > -1 && 'do something with 3'  || d.arraField.indexOf(4) > -1 && 'do something with 4'  : 'do nothing' }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the data structure of `data.json` file, the parent_id may be an `integer` or may be an `array of integers`.

Example of parent_id as an `integer`:

```
 {
  "id": 8,
  "name": "LG support",
  "parent_id": 5
 }
```

Example of parent_id as an `array`:

```
{
  "id": 7,
  "name": "UPS",
  "parent_id": [3, 4]
 }
```

In your code, however, you are not considering the second case (parent_id as an `array`).

So, in the `if` statement where you make this comparison, you have to add an `or` to handle cases where the row has parent_id as an array.

Instead of

```
if(value.parent_id == parent_id) {
  html_code += '<option value="'+value.id+'">'+value.name+'</option>';
}
```

You should use the code bellow that handles arrays as well (using the `Array.isArray()` and the `Array.include()` functions):

```
if(value.parent_id == parent_id || 
   (Array.isArray(value.parent_id) && value.parent_id.includes(+parent_id)))
{
   html_code += '<option value="'+value.id+'">'+value.name+'</option>';
}
```

Here is a complete working snippet (selecting service `delivery` in the first `<select>` will eventually present the `UPS` option in the third `<select>`):

(**Warning: in the snippet to make it work I have overriden the `$.getJSON`, DO NOT copy that part of the code**).

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

 load_json_data('service');

 function load_json_data(id, parent_id)
 {
  console.log('id = ' + id + ', parent_id = ' + parent_id);
  var html_code = '';
  $.getJSON('data.json', function(data)
  {
   html_code += '<option value="">Select '+id+'</option>';
   
   $.each(data, function(key, value)
   {
   //console.log(key + ' - ' + JSON.stringify(value));
    if(id == 'service')
    {
     if(value.parent_id == '0')
     {
      html_code += '<option value="'+value.id+'">'+value.name+'</option>';
     }
    }
    else
    {
     if(value.parent_id == parent_id || (Array.isArray(value.parent_id) && value.parent_id.includes(+parent_id)))
     {
      html_code += '<option value="'+value.id+'">'+value.name+'</option>';
     }
    }
   });
   $('#'+id).html(html_code);
  });

 }

 $(document).on('change', '#service', function(){
  var service_id = $(this).val();
  if(service_id != '')
  {
   load_json_data('item', service_id);
   $('#contact').html('<option value="">Select contact</option>');
  }
  else
  {
   $('#item').html('<option value="">Select item</option>');
   $('#contact').html('<option value="">Select contact</option>');
  }
 });
 $(document).on('change', '#item', function(){
  var item_id = $(this).val();
  if(item_id != '')
  {
   load_json_data('contact', item_id);
  }
  else
  {
   $('#contact').html('<option value="">Select contact</option>');
  }
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$.getJSON = function(file, callback){
  var data = [
   {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Delivery",
    "parent_id": 0
   }, 
   {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Repair",
    "parent_id": 0
   }, 
   {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "Quick Deliver",
    "parent_id": 1
   }, 
    {
    "id": 4,
    "name": "Slow Deliver",
    "parent_id": 1
   }, 
   {
    "id": 5,
    "name": "Aircon",
    "parent_id": 2
   }, 
   {
    "id": 6,
    "name": "Television",
    "parent_id": 2
   }, 
   {
    "id": 7,
    "name": "UPS",
    "parent_id": [3, 4]
   }, 
   {
    "id": 8,
    "name": "LG support",
    "parent_id": 5
   },
   {
    "id": 9,
    "name": "Toshiba support",
    "parent_id": 6
   }
  ];
  callback(data);
};

</script>
<select id="service"></select>
<select id="item"></select>
<select id="contact"></select>
```

Comment: Hi Francisco Neto,

Thanks for answering my question which I couldn't solve for 3 days :D
My other workaround was to change all the parent_id to array instead.